# Tagging M4A Files

Tags: sveltekit, audio-streaming, svelte-3, m4a

I have a m4a file. How can I assign tags to it in the browser using javascript? It has mp4a.40.5 codec. I'm using sveltekit@4.2.7 with sveltekit@2.0.0

Tried writing tags to it using browser-id3-writer but it didn't tag the file properly